# Convert xml to data frame with duplicated columns

Tags: r, xml

I have two problems with a xml-file. First there are duplicated columnnames ("timestamp" and "id") and data.table put them in one column instead separate them in different cols. Second, the data.table example below produces a lot of NA´s that should be filled with reps of Values.

```
 <Node1 timestamp="start">                            
    <Node2 id="1110" Value1="345">              
        <Node3 id="500" timestamp="1">               
            <Node4 id="484663" Value2="130" Value3="1,2,3" /> 
            <Node4 id="253234" Value2="59"  Value3="1,2,3" />   
            <Node4 id="198476" Value2="131" Value3="1,2,3" />  
        </Node3>                                      
        <Node3 id="501" timestamp="2">
            <Node4 id="305943" Value2="444" Value3="1,2,3" />
        </Node3>
        <Node3 id="601" timestamp="5">
        </Node3>
        <Node3 id="113" timestamp="3">               
            <Node4 id="2009343" Value2="555" Value3="1,2,3" /> 
            <Node4 id="2530931" Value2="333"  />   
            <Node4 id="1984761" Value2="111" Value3="1,2,3" />  
        </Node3>                                      
    </Node2>                                        
 </Node1>
```

I used the following lines to get a data frame. But there are a lot of NA´s and the "id" and "timestamp" values are mixed in one column. How can I force data.table to produce three id cols and repeat the Values, instead of putting NA´s in and write ?

```
library(data.table)                                                                       
library(XML)                                                                              
# test.xml = the xml-file 

test <- xmlTreeParse("test.xml",  useInternalNodes=TRUE)                                  

Node1 <- rbindlist(lapply(test["//*"], function(x)as.list(xmlAttrs(x))), fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

The result should look like this..

```
timestamp  id      Value1  id     timestamp    id       Value2  Value3
start      1110    345     500    1            484663   130     1,2,3
start      1110    345     500    1            253234   59      1,2,3
start      1110    345     500    1            198476   131     1,2,3
start      1110    345     501    2            305943   444     1,2,3
start      1110    345     601    5            NA       NA      NA
start      1110    345     113    3            2009343  555     1,2,3
start      1110    345     113    3            2530931  333     NA
start      1110    345     113    3            1984761  111     1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through nodeset and pass it to `xmlAncestors`, which will traverse the nodeset from `node4` to `node1` and use `xmlAttrs()` to get the attribute values at each level of the hierarchy. If there is no `node4`, then the entire traversal tree will be ignored. After completing `node4`, do the same thing again one node down - `node3` and merge two data together.

**work from node4**

```
a1 <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Node4", xmlAncestors, xmlAttrs)
a1_len <- lengths( a1 )
nm <- make.unique( names( a1[[ which( a1_len == max( a1_len ))[1] ]] ) )
a1 <- lapply( a1, function( x ) {
  require('data.table')
  nm_x <- make.unique( names(x) )

  if( ! all( nm %in% nm_x ) ) {
    x [ (nm [ which( ! nm %in% nm_x ) ]) ] <- NA
  }

  x <- cbind.data.frame( x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
  colnames( x ) <- make.unique( colnames( x ) )
  setDT(x)
  setcolorder( x, nm )
  return( x ) 
})

a1 <- rbindlist( a1 )
a1
#    timestamp   id Value1 id.1 timestamp.1    id.2 Value2 Value3
# 1:     start 1110    345  500           1  484663    130  1,2,3
# 2:     start 1110    345  500           1  253234     59  1,2,3
# 3:     start 1110    345  500           1  198476    131  1,2,3
# 4:     start 1110    345  501           2  305943    444  1,2,3
# 5:     start 1110    345  113           3 2009343    555  1,2,3
# 6:     start 1110    345  113           3 2530931    333     NA
# 7:     start 1110    345  113           3 1984761    111  1,2,3
```

**work from Node3**

```
b1 <- t( xpathSApply(doc, "//Node3", xmlAncestors, xmlAttrs) )
b1 <- data.frame( matrix( unlist( b1 ), 
                          nrow = nrow(b1),
                          ncol = ncol(b1),
                          dimnames = list( NULL, colnames( b1 ) ) ), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
b1
#   timestamp   id Value1 id.1 timestamp.1
# 1     start 1110    345  500           1
# 2     start 1110    345  501           2
# 3     start 1110    345  601           5
# 4     start 1110    345  113           3
```

**Merge a1 and b1:**

```
merge(a1, b1, all = TRUE)
#    timestamp   id Value1 id.1 timestamp.1    id.2 Value2 Value3
# 1:     start 1110    345  113           3 2009343    555  1,2,3
# 2:     start 1110    345  113           3 2530931    333     NA
# 3:     start 1110    345  113           3 1984761    111  1,2,3
# 4:     start 1110    345  500           1  484663    130  1,2,3
# 5:     start 1110    345  500           1  253234     59  1,2,3
# 6:     start 1110    345  500           1  198476    131  1,2,3
# 7:     start 1110    345  501           2  305943    444  1,2,3
# 8:     start 1110    345  601           5      NA     NA     NA
```

**Data:**

```
library('XML')
doc <- xmlParse(' <Node1 timestamp="start">                            
    <Node2 id="1110" Value1="345">              
                <Node3 id="500" timestamp="1">               
                <Node4 id="484663" Value2="130" Value3="1,2,3" /> 
                <Node4 id="253234" Value2="59"  Value3="1,2,3" />   
                <Node4 id="198476" Value2="131" Value3="1,2,3" />  
                </Node3>                                      
                <Node3 id="501" timestamp="2">
                <Node4 id="305943" Value2="444" Value3="1,2,3" />
                </Node3>
                <Node3 id="601" timestamp="5">
                </Node3>
                <Node3 id="113" timestamp="3">               
                <Node4 id="2009343" Value2="555" Value3="1,2,3" /> 
                <Node4 id="2530931" Value2="333"  />   
                <Node4 id="1984761" Value2="111" Value3="1,2,3" />  
                </Node3>                                      
                </Node2>                                        
                </Node1>  ')
```